# Java reflection, is there an easy way to get field value by 'field path'?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a pretty complex class, like,

```
classA {
  public classB b;
}

classB {
  public classC c;
}

classC {
  public List<classD> d;
}
...
```

Now, given an instance of classA, and a field path like 'b.c.d.e.f.g', is there an easy way to get the target field value via reflection? Any existing library or something?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Comment: Mind that a class can have multiple fields with the same name. So when you have a path like `b.c …` referring to an instance of `classA`, is `c` supposed to always refer to the field declared by `classB` (because the field `b`’s static type is `classB`) or should it resolve to a field declared by a subclass of `classB` if `b` refers to an instance of a subclass of `classB` that has such a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the post.

Thanks Tim, commons-beanutils helps a lot when handling pojo classes, it works pretty fine for List/Map field.

This is almost what I need, except a few edge cases, for example, when giving a List with no index provided.

I think the way to go is to write my own tool with the help of commons-beanutils.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an "easy" way (and there is definitely not an easy way to navigate into a List of `classD` elements by using a field path like `b.c.d.e.f`, as (at some point) you would need to specify which element in the `List` you are looking at.

Nevertheless, we can use reflection to navigate down a queue of fields. And despite the fact that in this simple example, we cannot pick elements from a `List`, we can still examine properties of the `List` itself, such as `size`.

*(example below accesses this private variable directly* -- definitely **not advised** -- *but your question is about reflection, so we brush these other important concerns aside for the purpose of illustration)*

For this particular example, the resulting output will be `RESULT of b.c.d.size: 3`, since we have stuffed three `new ClassD()` objects into that `List` when initializing variables.

```
public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception
{
    // Initialize all variables
    final ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.b = new ClassB();
    a.b.c = new ClassC();
    a.b.c.d = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ClassD(), new ClassD(), new ClassD()));

    // Traverse these member variables
    final String fieldPath = "b.c.d.size";

    // Build the list of paths from the string
    final Queue<String> fieldPaths = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(fieldPath.split("\\.")));

    // Display the output
    System.out.println("RESULT of ".concat(fieldPath).concat(": ").concat(discover(a, fieldPaths).toString()));
}

public static Object discover(final Object o, final Queue<String> fieldPaths) throws Exception
{
    // End of the queue, return the object found most recently
    if (fieldPaths.isEmpty())
    {
        return o;
    }

    final String nextFieldPath = fieldPaths.remove();
    final Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(nextFieldPath);

    // Go ahead and access private/protected data anyway... it's fine! what could go wrong 
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return discover(f.get(o), fieldPaths);
}

protected static class ClassA
{
    public ClassB b;
}

protected static class ClassB
{
    public ClassC c;
}

protected static class ClassC
{
    public List<ClassD> d;
}

protected static class ClassD
{
    // Empty block
}
```

Comment: The `PriorityQueue` returns the elements in their natural order, so it’s just a coincidence that it works in this example, because “`a`, `b`, `c`” is matching the natural order. You surely don’t want to sort the path elements, so use a queue that maintains the insertion order, like `ArrayDeque`. Further, `getDeclaredFields()` does not consider inherited fields, so you have to do either, iterate over the superclass hierarchy or use `getFields()` to get all public fields of the class hierarchy.

Comment: But why implement this search loop anyway, as you can call `getDeclaredField(String name)` or `getField(String name)` which do exactly that? Further, instead of `null == fieldPaths.peek()` you can write the idiomatic `fieldPaths.isEmpty()`. And when you have this `for (final String next : s.split("\\."))` loop anyway, you can perform the action directly in this loop instead of copying the elements into a queue and introduce a second, recursive approach.

Comment: There, fixed. You are correct on all counts. (First version was, after all, just a quick job.)

Comment: You don´t need to test the result of `getDeclaredField` for `null`. That´s what exception are for. If the field is not present, the next statement will never be reached. Instead, the closest exception handler for `NoSuchFieldException` will be entered. But note that you´re still not checking the superclasses in that case.